# vb.net - get unique entries from datatable using LINQ and copy result into another datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I'm sorry I know this has already been asked a thousand times but I just can't figure out what to do so I would really appreciate any hint.

I have a huge datatable with quite a few columns and over 200000 rows, now I want to get all the rows that have a distinct value in one column from this datatable and continue using them as a datatable.

First I want to get all the unique entries by using LINQ:

```
Dim query = From row In d1.AsEnumerable() Select row.Field(Of String)("Key") Distinct
```

then I want to copy these into another datatable:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable
```

however the `query.CopyToDataTable` doesn't work

> 'CopyToDataTable' is not a member of 'EnumerableRowCollection(of
>   IEnumerable(Of Char))'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `CopyToDataTable` with `DataRows` not with strings.

What you want to do with those rows which don't contain `Key`-column values which are unqiue? Do you want to omit all rows or only the duplicates(keep the first)?

You can use `EmumerableGroupBy`. If you want to keep the first:

```
Dim keyGroups = d1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("Key"))
Dim dt As DataTable = keyGroups.Select(Function(g) g.First()).CopyToDataTable()
```

If you want only those which are unique:

```
Dim dt = keyGroups.Where(Function(g) g.Count() = 1).Select(Function(g) g.First()).CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: Thanks! The "Key" column already contains a string consisting out of the merged values in the other columns - so only keeping the first one is good enough.